# How to change developer email from OAuth Screen?

Tags: email, oauth

I'm developing a feature that makes use of Google's OAuth Screen. The code part is all configured and ready, however, when the consent screen appears in the application a developer email from a former employee of ours appears and I don't know how to change this email to validate our app. Would anyone know where I can change this developer email?

[image: OAuth Screen]

I already looked for my project on Play Console, Firebase and Google Cloud but I couldn't find this email anywhere to edit

Answer (score 0):

on the Oauth2 consent screen click Edit app

[image]

User support email is the one you want to change

[image]

as well as Developer contact information at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made this change and am waiting for Google to verify it, however the support and developer email that was defined is not the same as the one that appears on the consent screen, which I find strange. Only if somehow the project is not the same, but I don't believe this is the case

Comment: I would double check the client you are using in your app to be sure and remove the email of your old employee they shouldn't have access anymore